# How to handle app.config wiht .netReactor Obfuscating

Tags: c#, .net, app-config, obfuscation

Is it possible to hide the app.config file within the obfuscated application with .net Reactor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its not required that the settings change at any point for that particular build then it is recommended they are hard coded into the executable and then appropriate levels of obfuscation are set to hide them in the end result binary.